# Alternative to Eco templates with multiline

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript

I used Eco templates for some time, but I don't like at all. I have searched some alternatives in Google, but I don't get useful information.

I am looking for templates with this features:

1. Multiline
2. Clear syntax
3. Rails 3.x supported
4. CoffeeScript supported
5. Backbone supported

Comment: You haven't elaborated on what you don't like about the Eco template solution. "Clear syntax?" That's highly subjective. Backbone can work with really any templating system. I don't understand the connection betwwen #3 and #4? Why would a templating system not work with one or the other of those?

Comment: For me, clear syntax means Haml in front of ERB for example.
#3 and #4 are because I have read there are some engines like JST that works with rails but others don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommand haml-coffee, integrates really well, or maybe jade :).